# Plotting an upper envelope function in Excel

Tags: excel, function, envelope

I have got data points of a sound sample from Audacity which I exported to a .txt file and imported in Excel. Is it possible to plot an upper envelope function in Excel?

(In the end I have to determine the reverberation time, so the time in which the loudness decreases with 60dB.)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that as well, but It's a sample of 1,6 seconds with a sample rate of 44100, so that means I have to pick out of 70560 data points (times 6 because I have to do it for 6 files) So that's a bit too much work unfortunately...

Comment: I don't believe that upper envelope is the right term here. This term is normally used for the upper envelope of a set of multiple functions. Seems as if you only have data points (x,y) (time, DB)? of one function. So maybe your requirement is to connect the peaks (local maximums) of this function? But also maybe I am wrong. Can you please post a short (but not too short) sample of the data you have?

Answer (score 1):

For a decaying oscillation such as this or a damped pendulum, the decay envelope can be found by looking at the difference between each sampled reading. You then need to see where the  is a change in gradient from +ve to -ve. (or zero on one side). To do this some logical operators are used.

Method:

Consider data starting at column A row 5 for time and Column B row 5 for first data value.

Create a column which has the value minus the previous value. `[ C6=B6-B5 etc.]`
Next do a column for the gradient change giving a "flag" of 1 for a positive  to negative or zero inflection `[D7= IF (AND(C7>0,C6<=0],1,0)`
This should produce a column of data that corresponds to the peaks.

In the next columns use the flag to get the original co-ordinates to display
`[E7 =IF (D7=1,A7,"")]` For time and `[F7 IF(D7=1,B7,"")]`

Copy this data using "Value" only in the paste option to yet another column.
Filter this to exclude the null data.
Beware of aliasing in data set.

Not the most elegant of solutions (and some steps can be linked -for clarity shown separately)  but it works.
Tech99m